# HP Notebook NC8000 multibay 40 GB SATA installed disk seen as 9 GB in MultiWord DMA2

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd

I've installed 40 GB A-data S599 SATA SSD in Multibay but it's being shown as 9 GB and works only in MultiWord DMA 2 mode (about 30 MB/s).

How to correct this ?

I'm using Samsung HM160HC 160 GB PATA in HDD bay, and standard COMBO in DVD bay.

Comment: What does it say in Disk Management? The disk might be partitioned.

Comment: No. It says the same. Disk is 9 GB.

Comment: Could you put up a screenshot of Disk Management?

Comment: This is not related to Disk Management. It's has something to do with SATA caddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was disk issue only in this notebook. Installed Kingston V200 128 GB capacity is fine. Then installed A-Data S396 30 GB also fine.

Comment: Yes some SSD's have issues in notebooks because of mobile chipsets.

Comment: I'm using 30 GB as a system disk and 160 GB as a storage disk. All is flying now ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've changed speed UDMA6 with hdparm for Windows:

```
hdparm -X udma6 /dev/sda
```

Now instead of 31/24 MB/s I'm getting 98/24 MB/s !!!

Comment: Now I need to figure out how to speedup write speeds with BAR-edit.